# Creating Objects in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

There are two ways of [instantiating objects in Clojure](http://clojure.org/java_interop), with the `new` function or the `.` macro:

```
(new Object)
(Object.)
```

The majority of code I've seen uses the latter macro.  I realise it's shorter, but the former seems much more readable to me.  That's just a matter of preference, but is there a technical reason to use the latter macro?

Comment: There are two *Java interop* ways of creating objects in Clojure. Almost everything you do creates *JVM* objects. A symbol is an object, as is a vector and a lazy sequence. Even a function is an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. [They are exactly the same](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_the_dot_special_form). The latter expands into the former at macro expansion time.

Comment: Indeed: `(macroexpand '(Object.)) ;= (new Object)`.

Comment: Right, I realise that at runtime there's no difference.  So presumably it's just preference that's caused people to choose the macro form.  I consider it to be less readable, but the majority seem to disagree.   I was wondering whether there's another language somewhere or something that this syntax derives from.

Comment: It's nice to be able to think of the constructors and methods as if they were functions.